# How to import a folder in scss?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

in bootstrap file, you can find

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
```

They are actually the folders, when I tried on my local machine, it doesn't work, the gulp saids mixins is not found. Any clues?

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are not folders, they're `.scss` files.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_mixins.scss

The underscores indicate that they are [partials](http://sass-lang.com/guide).

> The underscore lets Sass know that the file is only a partial file and that it should not be generated into a CSS file. Sass partials are used with the `@import` directive.